# Is a kable() col heading with side by side special symbols possible?

Tags: r, latex, kable

This is not a question about printing distinct `kable()` tables side by side.

Working in Markdown, PDF output. I have a column heading that is the Greek symbol delta. I want to add a column the heading of which is the Greek symbol delta side-by-side with the % symbol, but I cannot figure out how to achieve this.

Here's what I've got:

```
test_results <- dplyr::data_frame ('First Score'=c(42.35), 'Second Score'=c(90.4), '$\\Delta$'=c(48.05))

kable(test_results, align = "ccc", caption = "Test Results Data", format="latex", position = "h!", escape = FALSE) %>% row_spec(0,bold=TRUE) %>% 
kable_styling()
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: where did you try adding the `%` symbol? I don't see it anywhere

Comment: Is this being used in an `rmarkdown` document?

Comment: @Peter yes, with PDF output.

Comment: @r2evans, I've nothing to show as I've no idea how to print the `%` side-by-side with the delta

Comment: I know that LaTeX doesn't like the `%` symbol by itself, do I'd think something like `names(test_results)[3] <- "$\\Delta$\\%"` would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure where you want the % sign, so assuming it is required after the delta, try this.

````
```{r }

library(kableExtra)
library(tibble)

test_results <- tibble ('First Score'=c(42.35), 
                               'Second Score'=c(90.4), 
                               '$\\Delta$\\%'=c(48.05))

kable(test_results, 
      align = "ccc",
      caption = "Test Results Data", 
      format="latex", 
      position = "h!", 
      escape = FALSE) |> 
  row_spec(0,bold=TRUE) |>  
  kable_styling()


```
````

Which gives:

[image]